# appending query string and order of rewrite_rules

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have the following:

```
RewriteRule ^privacy/$ index.php?page=privacy
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?bucket_id=$1
```

How can I append them a possible query string?

so you could for example have `privacy/?logout` url, which will still be valid.
And why don't they work in the correct order? meaning that it uses the last rule when I try to access the privacy url, I know that's because the rules are similar as the 1st one is a private case of 2, but I thought they were supposed to work in the order I wrote them.

Answer (score -1):

use the QSA flag:

```
RewriteRule ^privacy/$ index.php?page=privacy [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?bucket_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

so when you will access: privacy/?logout

the $_GET['logout'] (in php for example) will be set (without a value)